# Issue parsing JSON arrays (unexpected end / undefined xhr.responseText)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest

```
  {
 "requirements": [
  {
   "name": {
      "required":true,
      "type":"string",
      "length":{"min":3}
    }
   },
    {
    "phone": {
      "type":"number",
      "required":true
    }
   }
 ],
 "people": [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Jim",
    "Phone":0123456789
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Jack",
    "Phone":4738383838
  }
 ]
}

function request (method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
           val = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log (val.people[1]);
      }
      xhr.open(method, url, true);
      xhr.send(null);
}
```

I'm having issues parsing this JSON. Before it was invalid, but I fixed it. Now, it comes up as undefined or it tells me that there was an unexpected end to the JSON. I'm not 100% sure if val.people[1] is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The parser is stumbling on the leading zero of the following integer: `0123456789`.

It's treating it as an octal number.